# NDB query based on Model's KeyProperty instance value

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have two models:

```
class Project:
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    status = ndb.StringProperty()
    == Other fields ==

class Task:
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    project = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Project, required=True)
```

I need query object which contains all tasks whose project status is "In-Progress". I am doing :

```
tasks = [task for task in Task.query() if task.project.get().status == "In-Progress"
```

This returns the list of tasks, but what I want is query object which can be used to call fetch_page for pagination.

I can't use: `tasks = Task.query(Task.project.get().status == "In-Progress")`

Is there anyway to do it? Thanks for any help..

Comment: Did you look at the [documentation for NDB queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries)? What about it is not clear?

Comment: I didn't say that its not clear. If you look at my question, I want to list all tasks of "In-Progress" project status. I want to implement pagination in this task page, for pagination to work we need query instance, so that we can user query.fetch_page(1). fetch_query is the instance of query class. Please have a look into https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#Query_fetch_page. I think it is clear now.

Comment: You won't be able to, your effectively doing a join. Push the project status down into the Task. Then you can do it.

Comment: @TimHoffman: Thanks for the reply. You mean that each task should have property that stores its corresponding project status? If so, I need to do this in every page where pagination is needed.

Comment: You would only do that, where you need to do a join.  Your problem is that you have to fetch the project to filter, so you are unable to use the queries capability to manage the pagination for you, or use cursors for that matter.

Comment: @TimHoffman: You understood my problem correctly, thanks. Join is there in most of the pages, so got to change the code. Is there any better way to do pagination. If you have any suggestion..please let me know.

Comment: @TimHoffman: Too much changes required in the code -  I can't add new field to each of the Model classes just to do pagination. So, I went for client-side pagination using jquery tablesorter pager(http://tablesorter.com/docs/). Its works fine, but it is in-efficient. Hope this discussion helps someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others have said in the comments, the problem you have is that your project status isn't part of the task. However, to make this kind of query efficient, you **need** to denormalize (which would involve adding project status to the task model).

If you would rather not denormalize, then you should be doing the gets for project asynchronously. This will make your request more efficient (less cost to you and faster to return values).

Something like the following (haven't tested):

```
@ndb.tasklet
def callback(task):
  project= yield tast.project.get_async()
  task.fetched_project = project
  raise ndb.Return(task)

#fetch the tasks, you could do paging here.
tasks = Task.query().fetch_page(20)

#map projects onto tasks
results = yield map(callback, tasks)

#filter tasks based on project (fetched_project now exists on task) status:
tasks = [task for task in results if task.fetched_project.status == "In-Progress"]
```

I recommend reading up about tasklets [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async#tasklets).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am into different module now. When I get time, I will try your method. One query: I think many could have faced similar problem, would they do denormalization? Doesn't it increase their datastore usage?

Comment: Yes you would usually denormalize. In appengine (because there are no joins) you typically denormalize to make reads faster. So you do more work at write time (to make your reads faster). Yes it'll use more storage, but less instance hours when running your query. However, if the query is seldom run (and isn't really a massive performance bottleneck for your application), then denormalization isn't always necessary. Take a read through this post http://bjk5.com/post/54202245691/the-app-engine-way

Comment: Link is great. I'm still getting into "App engine way" of doing stuffs.:D. I think I would have to redesign my models. 
BTW, I'm new to app engine and I'm doing my best. It would help me a lot if you have any any other links or any well written App engine application that you know. Thanks.

Comment: This site has quite a few links: http://www.gaecupboard.com/ also checkout reddit: http://www.reddit.com/r/AppEngine/

Comment: Going through these links. Thanks.